# Dovecot throws obsolete warnings, even though dovecot.conf updated on Ubuntu 11

Tags: ubuntu, dovecot

In trying to set up SASL for dovecot on Ubuntu 11, I keep getting obsolete warnings in my log:

```
Sep 10 15:33:53 server1 dovecot: config: Warning: Obsolete setting in 
/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf:24: passdb  {} has been replaced by passdb { driver= }
Sep 10 15:33:53 server1 dovecot: config: Warning: Obsolete setting in 
/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf:27: userdb  {} has been replaced by userdb { driver= }
```

Even though my dovecot.conf file looks like this:

```
protocols = none
auth default {
   mechanisms = plain login
   passdb {
       driver=pam
   }
   userdb {
       driver=passwd
   }
   socket listen {
     client {
       path = /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
       mode = 0660
       user = postfix
       group = postfix
   }
}
```

}

Even when I try:

```
driver=etc/pam.d/dovecot
driver=etc/passwd
```

I still get the same error. Looking at the example config file:

```
cat /usr/share/doc/dovecot-common/dovecot/example-config/dovecot.conf
```

was of no help. Dovecot is running:

```
ps -A | grep 'dovecot'
9663 ?        00:00:00 dovecot
```

But I can't seem to get that elusive "dovecot-auth" process. Anyone know what's going on?

New dovecot.conf file:

```
# 2.0.13: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 3.0.0-12-server x86_64 Ubuntu 11.10
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
protocols = none
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
}
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
userdb {
   driver = passwd
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`doveconf`](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveconf) to convert your configuration file into v2.x format:

```
doveconf -n -c /oldpath/dovecot.conf > /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf.new
```

Comment: didn't work for me. kept getting the errors. This: "doveconf -n > dovecot-new.conf"                                                     "mv dovecot-new.conf /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf" did work for me. However it's still not authenticating (no "dovecot-auth" process):(

Comment: It is another problem. Append the additional info to your original question.

Comment: appended new dovecot.conf that was outputted